# EditForm.aspx & Source parameter : redirect to an external URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, csom, edit-form

When you edit a list item properties, you can redirect the user to a specific page when the user click on the save button. It worked nice until I tried to test it with an external web server.

So far, only localhost and same sharepoint server URLs do the redirection, when I try with an external one (my Azure hosted web server or Google), clicking the save button will just download the edited file.

I have this issue with both on-premise and online SharePoint servers.

This will works:

`https://myserver.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=42&Source=https://myserver.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/`

This will works too:

`https://myserver.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=42&Source=https://localhost:42135/Debug/`

And this won't work:

`https://myserver.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=42&Source=https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/Debug/`

Is there a way to force the server to accept my external URL? I need to redirect the user from the edit form to my web server and vice versa few times.

I'm using the CSOM API (in C#) and I can't custom the server side forms (it has to work with a fresh new SharePoint server), also I want this to works with both on-premise et online SharePoint server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is the actual behavior. If that is the case, the only option you have would be doing a double jump: redirect to a custom page that would do the actual redirect using the CSOM / Ecmascript. Will try to have a look and report if I find out anything different

Comment: I would like to provide the most OOB experience possible to the end user. I already think of a workaround on the end-user side (because I can't change others SP servers with my app) but I thought there was an option or something else that will allow me to pass external url to SharePoint. Plus, in february, I'm sure that I tested it with Google and it worked (wtf ?). Thanks anyway :)